# Unnable to encode character while reading email body

Tags: python, apache-nifi

I'm using this code in Apache NiFi to read email body (found it on stackoverflow also):

```
import email
import mimetypes
from email.parser import Parser
from org.apache.commons.io import IOUtils
from java.nio.charset import StandardCharsets
from java.io import BufferedReader, InputStreamReader
from org.apache.nifi.processors.script import ExecuteScript
from org.apache.nifi.processor.io import InputStreamCallback
from org.apache.nifi.processor.io import StreamCallback

class PyInputStreamCallback(InputStreamCallback):
    _text = None

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def getText(self) : 
        return self._text

    def process(self, inputStream):
        self._text = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)

flowFile = session.get()
if flowFile is not None :
    reader = PyInputStreamCallback()
    session.read(flowFile, reader)

    msg = email.message_from_string(reader.getText())
    body = ""

    if msg.is_multipart():
        for part in msg.walk():
            ctype = part.get_content_type()
            cdispo = str(part.get('Content-Disposition'))

            if ctype == 'text/plain' and 'attachment' not in cdispo:
                body = part.get_payload(decode=True)  # decode
                break
    else:
        body = msg.get_payload(decode=True)

    flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'msgbody', body.decode('utf-8', 'ignore'))

    session.transfer(flowFile, ExecuteScript.REL_SUCCESS)
```

It works OK in most scenarios, but sometimes I receive an error:
`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u041a' in position 4784: ordinal not in range(128)`

I never work with Python and tried to fix it with `.encode('utf-8')` at this line: `cdispo = str(part.get('Content-Disposition'))`, but it didn't help. Maybe I'm wrong with thought that problem is in this line.

Full error:

```
Processing failed: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: javax.script.ScriptException: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u041a' in position 4784: ordinal not in range(128) in <script> at line number 30
- Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u041a' in position 4784: ordinal not in range(128) in <script> at line number 30
- Caused by: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<script>", line 30, in <module>
  File "/opt/nifi/nifi-current/work/nar/extensions/nifi-scripting-nar-1.16.3.nar-unpacked/NAR-INF/bundled-dependencies/jython-standalone-2.7.2.jar/Lib/email/__init__$py.class", line 57, in message_from_string
  File "/opt/nifi/nifi-current/work/nar/extensions/nifi-scripting-nar-1.16.3.nar-unpacked/NAR-INF/bundled-dependencies/jython-standalone-2.7.2.jar/Lib/email/parser$py.class", line 82, in parsestr
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u041a' in position 4784: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: In which line of your code error occurred? It must be in an error message.

Comment: Added full error to post. Line 30 is an empty line, after `body = ""`

Comment: error message saying it's in line with `message_from_string`.

Comment: i would try to read flowfile as bytes `IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream)` and parse email from bytes: `email.message_from_bytes( bytes )`

Comment: Have you tried with .encode(encoding='utf-8',errors='ignore') ?